# Is it possible to build MonoDevelop 3 on Mac OSX 10.5.8 (Leopard)?

Tags: macos, dependencies, monodevelop, upgrade

A while ago I had downloaded MonoDevelop 3 for Mac, only to find out that it doesn't run on version 10.5.8 (Leopard). Later I found a terse statement on some obscure website (which I can't find now). I can't find anything on the MonoDevelop website about minimum system requirements for MD version 3.XX on a Mac.

Is it possible then to build MD 3 to run on my Mac Leopard machine, or am I stuck having to upgrade to Snow Leopard? Or, is there a dependency which requires a minimum version of Xcode (in the 4.xx series?) to build it?

If someone could even point me to some information about what I need to build it for my Mac, that would be great.

CHEERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions for building MonoDevelop on OS X are [here](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Mac_Support/Building_MonoDevelop_on_OS_X). I haven't built it on 10.5 in years but can't think of any major reason why it shouldn't work.  It has a build time dependency on some of the Unix tools from Xcode (make, autoconf etc) but an older Xcode should work fine, or you might be able to get them on Homebrew. The main dependency is Mono, and the GTK+ included with Mono, and I'm not sure what the dependency of those is - try the latest packages. There may be a few places in MD itself where we took minor dependencies on newer things (e.g. P/Invokes) that you could fix as you run into them.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!