# I want my development environment back: requirements that work to install MD 2.8.8.4 on my Mac

Tags: installation, monodevelop, osx-leopard

After trying to build the latest MonoDevelop (MD) 3 [like this ==>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704283/is-it-possible-to-build-monodevelop-3-on-mac-osx-10-5-8-leopard), I ran into some problems which I won't go into in this post, since right now I just want to get my original development environment back which was MD 2.8.8.4.

In trying to do my building I got the impression (likely after looking some things up on the internet) that I needed a more recent version of MDK, so I downloaded and installed MDK 2.10.10. After some struggle, I decided I'd give up (late at night) and I uninstalled my original MD 2.8.8.4, and cleaned out the trash, and of course I don't keep installer files around long on my Mac because I don't have a lot of extra space.

Ok, sorry about that detour! When I tried to reinstall MD 2.8.8.4, the application didn't launch, and I couldn't figure out why. I think it is related to libraries that it couldn't find. I tried to run some of my mono programs that worked before I started fooling around and lo and behold they couldn't find I think it was "glibsharpglue", so I did some hunting and found [this](http://www.mono-project.com/DllNotFoundException), which agreed with my findings, but I couldn't quite work out what to do. I also found something on the internet which indicated that maybe my MRE install was hatched. That agreed with my recollection of not having too much trouble installing MD and dependencies the first time. I don't remember having to do any work with configuring where libraries were located in order for things to run. Hmm. Anyway, I thought I'd back off and try an earlier download (**Documentation is still very sparse -or I can't seem to find it anyway- about what dependencies / versions system-wise, or even toolkit-wise (MRE, or MDK) are required to run a given version of MD.**).

So, long story short, I downloaded MRE 2.10_5 which I found [in the archives here](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/). After uninstalling 2.10.10, I installed 2.10_5, and lo and behold my previous mono applications that I have made worked fine! So then I thought, "great, now I can get my MD environment working fine". Ha! When I installed MD 2.8.8.4, after of course, installing the MDK (2.10_5), a notice popped up nicely telling me that I needed a minimum MRE of 2.10.4. Ok, so back to the uninstall, download, re-install process only to find that the MRE does not seem to know where the libraries are again, and my programs don't run, so I didn't even bother with trying to install any further. Then, I had a brilliant idea to install MRE / MDK 3.0.2 (the latest)... figuring that this should install nicely and "you'd think it might know where the libraries are". Ah, but how wrong was I. After I installed this version and tried to run my programs, it gave an error like "dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022 Trace/BPT trap". After looking this up, I discovered that I need Snow Leopard or >, (10.6 +).

**Now my question is, what version of MRE, and MDK can I use on my system that properly sets up library referencing and that works on Mac (OSX 10.5.8), so that I can get back my original development system MonoDevelop 2.8.8.4? Or, if no one knows that, what do I need to let MRE/MDK know where the libraries are?**

CHEERS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what worked to get me back. I decided I'd even downgrade my MD so I could get something working. Well, neither 2.8.6.5 nor MD 2.8.4.2 would work with MRE 2.10_5, so then I went back to older versions of MRE/MDK. I discovered that MRE 2.10.6_1 allowed my mono programs to run (it knew where to look for libraries), then I downloaded and installed MDK 2.10.6_1 and tried to run my mono programs ... ah failed to find libraries. So I thought maybe I'll go ahead and install the MRE again. And it my programs worked. Then I installed and ran MD 2.8.8.4, and **it worked!** So this appears to be what is needed to get MD 2.8.8.4 working on a Mac OSX 10.5.8: step 1) install MDK 2.10.6_1   2) install MRE 2.10.6_1  3) install MD 2.8.8.4

Does it have to be that complicated?
Are there other solutions (probably, but I've got what I need right now).
CHEERS!

---

I guess I'm a sucker for punishment. After I got everything working I thought, "now let's just try MRE 2.10.10 again ... and after installing it, again, my mono programs don't work. So, I uninstalled that, and got back to the above so I could do my work in MD 2.8.8.4 which appears to be the latest version I can run without stepping through the "dependency or library" issues in building my own. (It kind of reminds me of dependency "fun" I had when building X10 (or was is X11?) and Gnome back in 2000 or so with my slackware box.)

Comment: I noticed inside the "MonoDevelop.app", that "MonoDoc", and "Xamarin Update" both require a minimum of OSX 10.6. Sigh. . . ., Maybe, I should just upgrade to Snow Leopard? (The thing is, I have an old machine which may just not work so well on it. I think it meets the minimum hardware requirements ... you know one of those old white macbooks, at least it is an Intel Core 2 Duo, but it has the old GM 950 graphics chip)